# Insert row in UITableView - somthing is missing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview

I need to add 'ADD NEW ROW' cell to the table. And I add it but I have problem to finish it. In this 'setEditing' method I don't know what do I need to put in 'paths' array?

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];

    NSMutableArray* paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // fill paths of insertion rows here

    if( editing )
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    else
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

    [paths release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add objects of indexPath in this path array. You can create NSIndexPath instance as -

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
```

Comment: Yep saadnib is right. After you do that table will ask for a new row in tableView: rowForIndexPath: and this is the place where you should return new cell object

Comment: Thanks that's it. But just one more thing before I close question. When I press add button code goes into 'commitEditingStyle' method. But I don't understand something. Nothing asks me to enter new item name for my table?

Comment: Ok I will add new view for add item on add icon tap. I will make it as modal view.

Comment: what you mean by "Nothing asks me to enter new item name for my table?"

Comment: I was think that when I tap add icon that it will add new row and asks me to enter item name.